# How do i mask UIImage view inside UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimage, core-graphics

I was trying to mask the subview to super view but image view is not masked to super view

**How it's displaying**
[image: OUTPUT]

**How it suppose to be**

[image: OUTPUT 2]

**Code**

```
class TicketView: UIView {

    var img = UIImage(named: "social-event.jpg")
    var imageView = UIImageView()

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
        let width:CGFloat = 11
        let height:CGFloat = 11
        let roundLeft = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: -(width/2), y: -(height/2), width: width, height: height), cornerRadius: (height/2))
        let roundLeftBotton = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: -(width/2), y: (rect.height)-(height/2), width: width, height: height), cornerRadius: (height/2))
        let roundRight = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: (rect.width)-(width/2), y: -(height/2), width: width, height: height), cornerRadius: (height/2))
        let roundRightBottom = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: (rect.width)-(width/2), y: (rect.height)-(height/2), width: width, height: height), cornerRadius: (height/2))

        let roundRightMiddle = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: (rect.width*0.7)-(width/2), y: -(height/2), width: width, height: height), cornerRadius: (height/2))
        let roundRightMiddleBottom = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: (rect.width*0.7)-(width/2), y:
            (rect.height)-(height/2), width: width, height: height), cornerRadius: (height/2))
        path.append(roundLeft.reversing())
        path.append(roundLeftBotton.reversing())
        path.append(roundRight.reversing())
        path.append(roundRightBottom.reversing())
        path.append(roundRightMiddle.reversing())
        path.append(roundRightMiddleBottom.reversing())

        UIColor.green.setFill()
        path.fill()

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (rect.width * 0.7),  height: rect.height)
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        self.addSubview(imageView)


    }

}
```

**What i tried till now**

1) mask layer

2) cut the image

Comment: did you try adding mask to Image view before adding as subview?

Comment: @iOS_devloper Did you mean create a CAShapeLayer and mask it?

Comment: Yes. create CAShapeLayer and mask it on Imageview.

Comment: @iOS_devloper Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Make new image that has layer like your corner and put on your View as a mask.